# JS multiplier takes the current innerHTML value instead of only the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have a list of `<p>` tags generated from my PHP script. Each of them has a value, for example, "30" or "5" (`<p>30</p>`). I have a select list with some values. By selecting them you multiply the value of every `<p>` tag. The problem is when I multiply `<p>10</p>` by 2 I get 20. When I multiply it once more, this time by 3, I don't get 30, but 60. I know that js takes the value that is there in the `<p>` tag at the moment of executing the function, but I don't know how to make it take only the base (on page load) value.

```js
function multiply() {
  $('.tags p').each(function() {
    let multiply_val = document.querySelector(".multiply_ing").value;
    let ing = parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
    this.innerHTML = ing * multiply_val;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiply">
  <select class="multiply_ing" onchange="multiply()">
    <option value="0.5">0.5x</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1x</option>
    <option value="2">2x</option>
    <option value="3">3x</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="tags">
  <p>10</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use data-attributes.

Also use external event handlers and make sure your class is present on the tag (you were missing `ingredient`)

Also you can trigger the change, so it is the value of the select that initialises the content:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".multiply_ing").on("change", function() {
    let multiply_val = +this.value;
    $('.ingredient p').each(function() {
      let ing = +this.dataset.val;
      this.innerHTML = ing * multiply_val;
    });
  }).change(); // initialise
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiply">
  <select class="multiply_ing">
    <option value="0.5">0.5x</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1x</option>
    <option value="2">2x</option>
    <option value="3">3x</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="tags ingredient">
  <p data-val="10"></p>
  <p data-val="5"></p>
  <p data-val="2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just edited my post (wrong tag in the function, as you have noticed). Unfortunately, the code doesn't work for me. When I load the page I have "NaN" values, when I delete .change(); I have the correct values on page load, but after I try to multiply it, it displays "NaN".

Comment: My code does not care what is in the p tags. It generates them from the data attributes. Your server only needs to store the values in the attributes and my code as it is above will work. If you change other stuff it might not. The `+this.value;` only works if you do not use an inline event handler. I recommend you implement my script as it is created now

Comment: You are right, I haven't noticed data-val="x" in the P tag. Thank you!